# Rewrite in virtualsvc not working when authpolicy implemented - Istio

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I am following some of the instructions in https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/40579 to setup Istio with an custom oauth2 provider with keycloak.

I have a main ingress which is sending all the traffic on one host to istio-ingressgateway

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: istio-ingress-main
  namespace: istio-system
  spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - mlp.prod
      secretName: mlp-tls
  rules:
  - host: mlp.prod # A FQDN that describes the host where that rule should be applied
    http:
      paths:                            # A list of paths and handlers for that host
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:                      # How the ingress will handle the requests
          service:
            name: istio-ingressgateway # Which service the request will be forwarded to
            port:
              number: 80           # Which port in that service
```

My ingress gateway is defined as below

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: prod-gateway
  namespace : istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - 'mlp.prod'
```

One of my services is mlflow which is installed in mlflow namespace for which the virtual service is defined as below

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: gateway-vs-mlflow
  namespace: mlflow
spec:
  hosts:
    - '*'
  gateways: 
    - istio-system/prod-gateway
  http:
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: "/mlflow"
      rewrite:
        uri: " "
      route:
      - destination:
          host: mlflow-service.mlflow.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 5000
```

Now when i try to access the host mlp.prod/mlflow/, I am able to access MLFLOW without any issues and the UI comes up correctly.

However if i try to add an oauth provider in an authpolicy towards the /mlflow route, then I get 404 page not available after the oauth authentication is done

The authpolicy is as in the below

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: oauth-policy
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: istio-ingressgateway
  action: CUSTOM
  provider:
    name: "oauth2-proxy"
  rules:
  - to:
    - operation:
        paths: ["/mlflow"]
```

Please assist in this issue. Is the rewrite in Virtual service supposed to work only without authpolicy with oauth2-proxy provider

Kindly help

Thanks,
Sujith.

```
Version
istioctl version
client version: 1.15.2
control plane version: 1.15.2
data plane version: 1.15.2 (8 proxies)

kubectl version --short
Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The --short output will become the default.
Client Version: v1.24.2
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.22.9
WARNING: version difference between client (1.24) and server (1.22) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by setting the oauth config with the below new value

upstreams="static://200"

Once this was done the oauth2 started returning 200 for authenticated users and everything was fine.